# Why is the sort of a bound variable forced not to be a finite_domain_sort?

Tags: z3, z3py

I find the behavior of bound variables of a finite domain sort
puzzling.  The following code shows they do not satisfy the
is_finite_domain_sort predicate.  Any idea why?

```
from z3 import *

U=FiniteDomainSort('U', 3)
V=FiniteDomainSort('V', 2)

u=Const('u', U)
x=Const('x', U)
y=Const('y', V)
p=Function('p', U, V, BoolSort())

expr=Exists([x, y], And(p(x,y), Not(x == u)))

print "Z3 version"
print ">>> get_version()"
print get_version()
print "Is U finite?"
print ">>> is_finite_domain_sort(U)"
print is_finite_domain_sort(U)
print "Is sort of bound var equal to U?"
print ">>> expr.var_sort(0)==U"
print expr.var_sort(0)==U
print "Is sort of bound var finite?"
print ">>> is_finite_domain_sort(expr.var_sort(0))"
print is_finite_domain_sort(expr.var_sort(0))
print "Why isn't the sort of the bound variable finite?"
```

The output on a Mac:

```
$ python findom.py
Z3 version
>>> get_version()
(4L, 4L, 2L, 1L)
Is U finite?
>>> is_finite_domain_sort(U)
True
Is sort of bound var equal to U?
>>> expr.var_sort(0)==U
True
Is sort of bound var finite?
>>> is_finite_domain_sort(expr.var_sort(0))
False
Why isn't the sort of the bound variable finite?
$
```

Comment: I can try to help but I'm not really familiar with the python API - Can you post the output of the SMTLIBv2 that is generated from your model?

Comment: I don't think you can write this formula in an SMTLIBv2.5 script.  I saw no mention of finite domain sorts in the standard.  This is all about creating a z3 expression with what appears to me to be odd properties.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior was due to a bug in our Python API. This has now been fixed (as of [this commit](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/commit/ead970b4778330768e64a04f13a46289f974cb85)) and it behaves as intended on the given example.